# SqlDataAdapter does not contain a constructor for 3 arguments

Tags: c#, sql, constructor

Please bear with me as but im getting a SqlDataAdapter does not contain a constructor for 3 arguments error when i try to pass the following sql query.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source = NY-L-WNORALES\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = CCH_ENT; Integrated Security = True");
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT CLIENTPARTNERSHIP.ClientIdent,CLIENTPARTNERSHIP.NameLine1,ClientType,ClientStatus,AddressLine1,Addr`essLine2,CityName,PostalCode,StateProvinceCode,BillManagerName,FirmClientStaffAssignmentName,StaffFirstName AS PartnerFirstName,StaffLastName AS PartnerLastName FROM CLIENTPARTNERSHIP JOIN CLIENT ON CLIENTPARTNERSHIP.ClientIdent = CLIENT.ClientIdent JOIN CLIENTADDRESS ON CLIENTPARTNERSHIP.ClientIdent = CLIENTADDRESS.ReferenceIdent JOIN CLIENTPRACTICE ON CLIENTPARTNERSHIP.ClientIdent = CLIENTPRACTICE.ClientIdent JOIN CLIENTCRS ON CLIENTPARTNERSHIP.ClientIdent = CLIENTCRS.ClientIdent JOIN STAFF ON STAFF.StaffIdent = CLIENTCRS.StaffIdent WHERE FirmClientStaffAssignmentName = 'Primary Partner' AND ClientSubId = '" + SearchBox.Text + "'", con + "UNION SELECT CLIENTCORP.ClientIdent,CLIENTCORP.NameLine1,Clientid,ClientSubId,ClientType,ClientStatus,AddressLine1,AddressLine2,CityName,PostalCode,StateProvinceCode,BillManagerName,FirmClientStaffAssignmentName,StaffFirstName AS PartnerFirstName,StaffLastName AS PartnerLastName FROM CLIENTCORP JOIN CLIENT ON CLIENTCORP.ClientIdent = CLIENT.ClientIdent JOIN CLIENTADDRESS ON CLIENTCORP.ClientIdent = CLIENTADDRESS.ReferenceIdent JOIN CLIENTPRACTICE ON CLIENTCORP.ClientIdent = CLIENTPRACTICE.ClientIdent JOIN CLIENTCRS ON CLIENTCORP.ClientIdent = CLIENTCRS.ClientIdent JOIN STAFF ON STAFF.StaffIdent = CLIENTCRS.StaffIdent WHERE FirmClientStaffAssignmentName = 'Primary Partner' AND ClientSubId = '" + SearchBox.Text + "'", con);
```

Comment: Simple answer: don't use string concatenation but parameterized queries. It won't only fix this issue but also more important like sql-injection vulnerability.

Comment: `SearchBox.Text + "'", con + "UNION SELECT` here is a typo

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the issue that you are facing is, you have specified connection(`con`) two times while creating the adapter instance. But still you are in trouble as you are going to be a victim of `SQL-Injection` So I strongly recommend you to use parameterization. You can try something like the following:

```
string querySql = "SELECT *query here* WHERE FirmClientStaffAssignmentName = 'Primary Partner' AND ClientSubId = @ClientSubId" +
                  " UNION SELECT *query here* WHERE FirmClientStaffAssignmentName = 'Primary Partner' AND ClientSubId = @UnionClientSubId";
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source = *******"))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmdSql = new SqlCommand(querySql, con))
    {
        cmdSql.Parameters.Add("@ClientSubId", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = SearchBox.Text;
        cmdSql.Parameters.Add("@UnionClientSubId", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = SearchBox.Text;
        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdSql)
        {
            sda.Fill(yourDataTable);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this hope its help you.

```
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source = NY-L-WNORALES\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = CCH_ENT; Integrated Security = True");
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT CLIENTPARTNERSHIP.ClientIdent,CLIENTPARTNERSHIP.NameLine1,ClientType,ClientStatus,AddressLine1,Addr`essLine2,CityName,PostalCode,StateProvinceCode,BillManagerName,FirmClientStaffAssignmentName,StaffFirstName AS PartnerFirstName,StaffLastName AS PartnerLastName FROM CLIENTPARTNERSHIP JOIN CLIENT ON CLIENTPARTNERSHIP.ClientIdent = CLIENT.ClientIdent JOIN CLIENTADDRESS ON CLIENTPARTNERSHIP.ClientIdent = CLIENTADDRESS.ReferenceIdent JOIN CLIENTPRACTICE ON CLIENTPARTNERSHIP.ClientIdent = CLIENTPRACTICE.ClientIdent JOIN CLIENTCRS ON CLIENTPARTNERSHIP.ClientIdent = CLIENTCRS.ClientIdent JOIN STAFF ON STAFF.StaffIdent = CLIENTCRS.StaffIdent WHERE FirmClientStaffAssignmentName = 'Primary Partner' AND ClientSubId = '" + " " + "' UNION SELECT CLIENTCORP.ClientIdent,CLIENTCORP.NameLine1,Clientid,ClientSubId,ClientType,ClientStatus,AddressLine1,AddressLine2,CityName,PostalCode,StateProvinceCode,BillManagerName,FirmClientStaffAssignmentName,StaffFirstName AS PartnerFirstName,StaffLastName AS PartnerLastName FROM CLIENTCORP JOIN CLIENT ON CLIENTCORP.ClientIdent = CLIENT.ClientIdent JOIN CLIENTADDRESS ON CLIENTCORP.ClientIdent = CLIENTADDRESS.ReferenceIdent JOIN CLIENTPRACTICE ON CLIENTCORP.ClientIdent = CLIENTPRACTICE.ClientIdent JOIN CLIENTCRS ON CLIENTCORP.ClientIdent = CLIENTCRS.ClientIdent JOIN STAFF ON STAFF.StaffIdent = CLIENTCRS.StaffIdent WHERE FirmClientStaffAssignmentName = 'Primary Partner' AND ClientSubId = '" + " " + "'", con);
```

Comment: So you have ignored `SearchBox.Text` to avoid injection, right? but why `'" + " " + "'`? why not simply `ClientSubId = ' ' UNION`?

Comment: right. Why you do not use store procedure. its helps you and manage your code also.

Answer (score 0):

Your sql is *totally unreadable*, that's why it's quite eqsy to make a simple mistake (typo) which is hard to be found. Let's make sql brushed (put it being *readable* and *parametrized*):

```
string sql = 
  @"SELECT CLIENTPARTNERSHIP.ClientIdent,
           CLIENTPARTNERSHIP.NameLine1,
           ClientType,
           ClientStatus,
           AddressLine1,
           AddressLine2,
           CityName,
           PostalCode,
           StateProvinceCode,
           BillManagerName, 
           FirmClientStaffAssignmentName,
           StaffFirstName AS PartnerFirstName,
           StaffLastName AS PartnerLastName 
      FROM CLIENTPARTNERSHIP JOIN 
           CLIENT ON CLIENTPARTNERSHIP.ClientIdent = CLIENT.ClientIdent JOIN 
           CLIENTADDRESS ON CLIENTPARTNERSHIP.ClientIdent = CLIENTADDRESS.ReferenceIdent JOIN 
           CLIENTPRACTICE ON CLIENTPARTNERSHIP.ClientIdent = CLIENTPRACTICE.ClientIdent JOIN 
           CLIENTCRS ON CLIENTPARTNERSHIP.ClientIdent = CLIENTCRS.ClientIdent JOIN 
           STAFF ON STAFF.StaffIdent = CLIENTCRS.StaffIdent 
     WHERE FirmClientStaffAssignmentName = 'Primary Partner' 
       AND ClientSubId = @prm_ClientSubId

     UNION 

    SELECT CLIENTCORP.ClientIdent,
           CLIENTCORP.NameLine1,
           Clientid,
           ClientSubId,
           ClientType,
           ClientStatus,
           AddressLine1,
           AddressLine2,
           CityName,
           PostalCode,
           StateProvinceCode,
           BillManagerName,
           FirmClientStaffAssignmentName,
           StaffFirstName AS PartnerFirstName,
           StaffLastName AS PartnerLastName
      FROM CLIENTCORP JOIN 
           CLIENT ON CLIENTCORP.ClientIdent = CLIENT.ClientIdent JOIN 
           CLIENTADDRESS ON CLIENTCORP.ClientIdent = CLIENTADDRESS.ReferenceIdent JOIN 
           CLIENTPRACTICE ON CLIENTCORP.ClientIdent = CLIENTPRACTICE.ClientIdent JOIN 
           CLIENTCRS ON CLIENTCORP.ClientIdent = CLIENTCRS.ClientIdent JOIN 
           STAFF ON STAFF.StaffIdent = CLIENTCRS.StaffIdent 
     WHERE FirmClientStaffAssignmentName = 'Primary Partner' 
       AND ClientSubId = @prm_ClientSubId";
```

It's easy now, right?

```
 SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);

 // Sorry: AddWithValue - easy (I don't know ClientSubId's type), but not the best   
 //TODO: change "AddWithValue" into "Add" and put actual ClientSubId's RDMBS type
 sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm_ClientSubId", SearchBox.Text);
```

**Side notes:** do not *hardcode* but *parameterize* you query:

1. Think of *SQL injection*: what if I put `"'; delete table Staff --"` in the `SearchBox.Text`.
2. Think of *performance*: you are going to have *many* very similar queries (instead of one) which will be parsed each time you perform them, moreover they will be put into parsed queries cache and prevent other queries to be cached